# Excel repeat cells

Tags: excel, function, concatenation, drag

I need and approach for this:
   
    `A     B      C
    1   house  1 house
    2   car    1 car
    3   boy    1 boy
    4          2 house
    5          2 car
               2 boy
               3 house
               3 car
               3 boy
               …`
I want to make a function that when I drag it down I get this result.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0) & " " & INDEX(B:B,IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,3,MOD(ROW(),3)))
```

and copy down

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&FLOOR(1+(ROW()-1)/3,1))&" "&INDIRECT("B"&MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1)
```